# Find rightmost column in table that fits criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've created a table with Postgres that counts the number of times an email address shows up in each level of a hierarchy. The levels of the hierarchy are ordered left to right - aka, Regions roll up into Brand, Areas roll up into Regions, and Sites roll up into Areas.

My goal is to populate the column "lowest_distinct_level" with the name of the lowest hierarchy level for which an email address is distinct. Here's an example table posted below:

```
email_address   | brand | region | area | site | lowest_distinct_level
----------------|-------|--------|------|------|----------------------
alpha@gmail.com |   1   |    1   |   1  |   2  |
beta@gmail.com  |   1   |    1   |   2  |   0  |
gamma@gmail.com |   1   |    1   |   2  |   2  |
zeta@gmail.com  |   1   |    2   |   0  |   0  |
```

- Alpha has its email show up in two Sites but only one Area, so lowest_distinct_level should be populated with "area".
- Beta has its email show up in two Areas but only one Region, so "region" should be populated.
- Gamma has its email show up in two Sites, but these two Sites are in different Areas. Thus, "region" should be populated.
- Zeta's row should say "brand".

In short, for each row I need to find the rightmost column with a value of 1, and output that column's name as a value to lowest_distinct_level. Is there a relatively efficient way to use PLPGSQL or arrays to accomplish this? I'm not very good at scripting or coding in general so apologies if this is trivial.

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored function?

Comment: Using arrays it could be `select ..., (array['site','area','region','brand'])[array_position(array[site,area,region,brand],1)] as lowest_distinct_level from ...`

Comment: What if the row is 1 2 2 1?  What do you want returned?

Comment: Hi Gordon, 1 2 2 1 cannot be returned due to how the hierarchy file is constructed - one site cannot possibly be tied to two separate areas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic solution using nested CASE:

```
select email_address, brand, region, area, site,
    case when site = 1 then 'site'
         else case when area = 1 then 'area'
              else case when region = 1 then 'region'
                   else case when brand = 1 then 'brand'
                             else ''
                             end
                        end       
                   end
         end as lowest_distinct_level 
from mm;
```

This is the result:

```
+-----------------+-------+--------+------+------+-----------------------+
| email_address   | brand | region | area | site | lowest_distinct_level |
+-----------------+-------+--------+------+------+-----------------------+
| alpha@gmail.com | 1     | 1      | 1    | 2    | area                  |
+-----------------+-------+--------+------+------+-----------------------+
| beta@gmail.com  | 1     | 1      | 2    | 0    | region                |
+-----------------+-------+--------+------+------+-----------------------+
| gamma@gmail.com | 1     | 1      | 2    | 2    | region                |
+-----------------+-------+--------+------+------+-----------------------+
| zeta@gmail.com  | 1     | 2      | 0    | 0    | brand                 |
+-----------------+-------+--------+------+------+-----------------------+
```

Abelisto has wrote a short version:

```
select email_address, brand, region, area, site,
    case when site = 1 then 'site'
         when area = 1 then 'area'
         when region = 1 then 'region'
         when brand = 1 then 'brand'
         else ''
    end as lowest_distinct_level
from mm;
```

Check it here: http://rextester.com/HSYJT82278

Comment: Thanks @McNets! The case statement works perfectly. I should have written this in the main question, but some more detail on what I'm doing - the ultimate goal is to make this work in a generic fashion, for any number of hierarchy columns (and names). I guess I could build a function to allow for this to work dynamically by generating the update script based off of parameters passed in.

Comment: @flamewheel using array_position and a lookup table you can get it easily.

Comment: Apparently I can't use array_position - explained it in another comment, but the Postgres version being run on the server is 9.3.9. array_position looks like it was added in 9.5. Not something that I'm able to upgrade at this point since I'm not a DBA :(

Answer (score 1):

This can indeed be solved with an array:

```
select *, 
       case array_position(array[site,area,region,brand],1)
         when 1 then 'site'
         when 2 then 'area'
         when 3 then 'region'
         else 'brand'
       end as lowest_distinct_level
from mm
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I'm apparently running an older version of Postgres... Didn't know array_position was a thing since that's apparently added in 9.5, and my computer has 9.3. I'm going to install 9.6 and try what you wrote. The bigger challenge for me is to make this generic - works with any number hierarchy fields.